# How to animate vertex color of an object?

Tags: animation, vertex-colors

Is it possible to animate the vertex color of an object?

Comment: perhaps you could clarify on the basis of _what_ you would like to animate it. A morph between two color layers, or something more procedural.

Comment: two possibilities:
- or to morph between two vertex colors layer in time
- or to change , in same vertex color layer, the colors in time

Comment: please update your question with more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Cycles

In *Cycles Render*, it's rather easy. Create your two *Color Layers* and animate the *MixRGB's Fac:* value.

[image]

I'm not familiar enough with Blender Internal to find a suitable answer for that engine. Luckily, [brecht](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/242/brecht) provided [an answer](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/22120)

#### Blender Internal

[image]

Comment: A similar setup works for Blender Internal, using two Geometry nodes for the vertex color, a Mix node to mix them and a Material node to plug the color into.

Comment: @brecht I tried and failed miserably, can you show a .blend?

Comment: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/22120

Comment: @brecht Thank you! I see, the viewport BI render doesn't seem to update (without switching from Render Preview to Texture Preview and back again), but a f12 regular render works fine.

Answer (score 2):

**manipulating Color Layer directly with Python as a function of frame number**

We can animate a color_layer vertex by vertex procedurally with `frame_change_pre handler`, docs for which are [here](http://www.blender.org/documentation/250PythonDoc). This assumes that there is a vertex color map called  'Col', and that you know how to render Vertex Colors

```
import bpy
import random

obj = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
mesh = obj.data

color_layer = mesh.vertex_colors["Col"]

def set_vcols(frame):
    i = 0
    for poly in mesh.polygons:
        for idx in poly.loop_indices:
            r = 0.5
            g = 255 / (frame % 255)
            b = random.random()
            color_layer.data[i].color = r,g,b
            i += 1

def my_handler(scene):
    frame = scene.frame_current
    set_vcols(frame)

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(my_handler)
```

If you go this route, while developing it might seem that your code is not being executed as you hoped, run the below code from console, then rerun your script:

**purge the event list:**

```
f_change = bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre
del f_change[0:len(f_change)]
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure what can i make with this code.
What are the steps to use this script?
I have creat a cube, asign to it a vertex colors named "Col", run the script, but nothing appears

Comment: I now how to render the vertex color, i want to animate this propertie:
example: all vertex are red at 0s and all are greens at 1s

Comment: a gradual change ?

Comment: yes exactly a gradual change

Comment: Blender internal, but if there is a technique juste for cycle,
i want to know too for my knoledge

Comment: In Cycles, you can render vertex colors by connecting an Attribute input node to a shader node (e.g., Glossy) connected to your Material Output node. The Attribute node passes to the shader node the individual vertex colors.